# ld: library not found for -lodbc on Mac

Tags: php, macos, pecl

On a new Mac with Big Sur we are trying to install a pecl package by running:

```
sudo pecl install sqlsrv
```

This ends with the error:

```
ld: library not found for -lodbc
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

We've tried many things by now such as appending a the --linker option to the pecl command, but this doesn't seem to work either:

```
sudo pecl install sqlsrv --linker="ld -L /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin -lodbc"
```

or:

```
sudo pecl install sqlsrv -L /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Anyone any ideas how to get past this error?

EDIT
No solution still. However, if I execute the following command:
ld -lodbc -v

The response is:

```
@(#)PROGRAM:ld  PROJECT:ld64-711
BUILD 14:59:28 Aug 21 2021
configured to support archs: armv6 armv7 armv7s arm64 arm64e arm64_32 i386 x86_64 x86_64h armv6m armv7k armv7m armv7em
Library search paths:
    /usr/lib
Framework search paths:
    /Library/Frameworks/
    /System/Library/Frameworks/
ld: library not found for -lodbc
```

which makes sense because ld is not in /usr/lib. It is in /usr/bin..

Comment: The error seems very clear. Do you have ODBC libraries installed? Have you followed the recommended [installation steps](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/developer-get-started/php/mac/?rtc=1)?

Comment: Yes, I have odbc libraries installed. And I followed the same steps but without the docker part because we don't require to run sql server in docker. The exact steps I followed are the ones described in the microsoft tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-ver15#installing-on-macos

Comment: My impression is that the 'ld' utility (or whatever it does) is shipped with xcode command tools, but somehow odbc doesn't seem to find it on the system. If only I knew where it is looking a symlink might do the trick

Comment: What's the location for libodbc?  Did you check that this location is on the library search path for the linker? This info should be explicit in the question.

Comment: well, the location of the ODBC driver lives in: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/msodbcsql17/17.8.1.1/include